# JPA Specification DDD - Advanced topic

Tags: jpa, domain-driven-design, criteria, specifications

Recently I developed a project in which I use DDD Specification with JPA predicate:

```
public interface Specification<T>{
  public boolean isSatisfiedBy(T object);
  Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<T> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb);
  ISpecyfikacja<T> and(ISpecyfikacja<T> specyfikacja);
  ISpecyfikacja<T> or(ISpecyfikacja<T> specyfikacja);
  ISpecyfikacja<T> not();
}
```

I have 3 entities 'A' and 'B' and 'C' with these relationships:
A oneToMany with B
C oneToMany with B

Then I created some specification for entity 'A' but conditions are connected with entity 'C', so I made joins.

```
root.join(A.b1).join(B.c1);
```

Everything is ok when there is one of that kind of specification, but not if there are two of them.

When I do `spec1.and(spec2).and(spec3).and(...)` I get:

ORM create query:

```
select a
from 
  A a,
  B b1,
  C c1,
  B b2,
  C c2,
  ...
where ...
```

If you have more of that kind of specification `and`ed with each other, this select becomes nightmare JOINS, because there should be use only one join, and apply predicate to it.

My question is:
How do I omit these joins?

**Update:**
Question is how to design specification to have single Join element for all specification in query. I know I need to reused variable, I need spread Join object all over specification.... how? by parameter, by constructor... It doesnt sound good

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are calling `join(A.b1)` multiple times and this will result in multiple joins. To have one join, only call it once and reuse the variable.

Comment: Ok I didnt make myself clear. Question is how to design specification to have single Join element for all specification in query.  I know I need to reused variable, I need spread Join object all over specification.... how? by parameter, by constructor... It doesnt sound good. I think solutions is to have container 'specificaitions' for specification for particular query, and this object would provide single join element(or create new one) as need for specification.